# CosmosDB DirectMode TCP is not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing an Azure CosmosDB project and we are now in the testing/optimization stages but we are facing an issue which, so far, has remained unanswered by the official documentation or other sources.

Essentially, whenever we use the .NET SDK configured under DirectMode and TCP protocol we alway hit an error regarding "Service is currently unavailable" or "Resource not found".

However, as soon as we remove this configuration from the .NET SDK client everything starts to work as it should.

I've found a couple github issues on this (as [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/80) or [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/194) for example) but on any of them does my use case apply.

I'm testing from a locally deployed WebAPI fetching data from an Azure Trial Account.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support) mentions that ports 10000-20000 should be open. I've manually added that configuration as well (Azure side) but still no success.

Is there any issue using this? Does this only work from within the same network? What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: _"Does this only work from within the same network?"_ If does sound a bit like an issue I had in Azure when machines were't in the same subnet (otherwise unrelated)

Comment: According to the docs on direct connection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#direct-connection) that should not be the case, but all option are still on the table ATM.